# How can I destroy a game object but have a particle effect after in unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I am now making a simple game and when the enemy dies it emit particles. But the problem is that once it has been destroyed then the particle effect stops. Is there a way to solve this problem? 
Any help is greatly appreciated! I am now using Unity 2019.3.9f1. Here is my code (enemy) -----

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("bomb"))
    {
        GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        Destroy(enemy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to instantiate the particle system before destroying the gameObject (creating new GameObject), and assign a lifetime to this new GameObject:

```
Destroy(newGameObject, secondsToDestroy);
```

You can also do something similar to: https://answers.unity.com/questions/610673/how-to-destory-a-gameobject-in-c-after-3-seconds.html

UPDATED

```
public ParticleSystem ps;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(ps.gameObject);
        Destroy(go, 10.0f);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand **Instantiating the particle system**, can you give me an example?

Comment: If you assign the particle system (saved as prefab for example) to a variable, you can Instantiate the prefab that contains the particle system. With this external gameobject, you can Destroy it with a concrete lifetime.

I propose that because if you Destroy your current gameObject, you will destroy the particle system that exists only inside your current gameObject.